# convert MatOfPoint to MatOfKeypoint

Tags: android, opencv

As what I'd wrote on title, I need a way to convert them. 
This is how i wish it to function:

1. detect feature points by FAST ( output: MatOfKeyPoint)
2. convert MatOfKeyPoint to Point, since pointPolygonTest requires Point type. (I managed to do this)
3. convert back to MatOfKeyPoint. DescriptorExtractor needs this type.

I'm stuck on the last step. 
Thanks.

Comment: most of the helps available are conversion from matofkeypoint to matofpoint, not the other way.

Comment: Why not just pass in the original `MatOfKeyPoint`?

Comment: pointPolygonTest accept Point as input only.
[link]http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#pointpolygontest[/link]

Comment: I mean pass the `MatOfKeyPoint` to the `DescriptorExtractor`. Either that or just use the `pt` field of `KeyPoint` in `pointPolygonTest()`. You might want to post some code so people have a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to use Descriptor Extractor on points that are in a contour. So i use pointPolygonTest to sort of like filter them out. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to do this is to populate a new `MatOfKeyPoint` with only the points which are inside the polygon, and then pass that to your `DescriptorExtractor`.

This is an example using the C++ API (I don't know the Java API), but I hope it points you in the right direction.

```
cv::Mat image;    //Your image
std::vector<cv::Point2f> contour;      //This is the contour you're testing
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;   //From FAST detection
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> in_polygon;

for (const cv::KeyPoint& key : keypoints)
{
    if (cv::pointPolygonTest(contour, key.pt, true) > 0)    //Inside polygon, ignore points on edge
    {
        in_polygon.push_back(key);
    }
}

auto extractor =  cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("ORB");    //ORB for example; I don't know which you're using
cv::Mat descriptors;
extractor->compute(image, in_polygon, descriptors);
```

You should be able to replicate this functionality with the `toList()` method of `MatOfKeyPoint`.

Comment: thanks! btw, do you have any idea on combination(feature detect, descriptor extractor and matcher) that will work better?
the combination im using right now is FAST,ORB,BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING

Comment: That depends on your definition of "better". Do you mean faster? More reliable matching? FAST, FREAK, and ORB are fairly cheap to compute, but SURF and SIFT generally provide much better matches. Ultimately, you have to run some tests to find the optimal combination.